# How to use discriminant in generic functions in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, generics, discriminated-union

When using discriminated unions with generics, I need to write some redundant code, which may also harmful to type safety.

```
interface Square {
    kind: "square";
    size: number;
}
interface Rectangle {
    kind: "rectangle";
    width: number;
    height: number;
}
interface Circle {
    kind: "circle";
    radius: number;
}
type Shape = Square | Rectangle | Circle;

function<T extends Shape> fetch(type: Shape['kind'], id: string): T {
  // fetch data from database via id
}
```

The problem is that there are redundant type specification in function `fetch`, I can use `Shape['kind']` to restrict type to be `'square' | 'rectangle' | 'circle'`, but calls like `fetch<Square>('circle', 'some-id')` will still compiles. How to solve this problem? Is there any way to define function like one of the following version?

1. `fetch<T extends Shape>(type: T['kind'], id: string):T`
2. `fetch<T extends Shape['kind']>(type: T, id: string): SomeMagic<T>` and `SomeMagic<T>` helps compiler to find proper type, like `SomeMagic<'square'>` infers `Square` in compile time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd recommend your "version 2" approach like this:

```
declare function fetch<T extends Shape['kind']>(
  type: T, 
  id: string
): Extract<Shape, {kind: T}>;
fetch<'square'>('circle', 'some-id'); //error
const shape = fetch('rectangle', 'some-id'); // shape is a Rectangle
```

The "magic" is the `Extract` type function defined [in the standard library](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.2.2/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1451-L1454), which is a [conditional type](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#conditional-types) that extracts matching elements from a union.

You *could* go with your "version 1" approach, but I don't recommend it:

```
declare function fetch<T extends Shape>(type: T['kind'], id: string): T;
fetch<Square>('circle', 'some-id'); //error
const shape = fetch('rectangle', 'some-id'); // shape is a Shape
```

Notice how the `type` parameter is `T['kind']`, not `Shape['kind']`. That fixes your problem as stated, but if you allow the compiler to infer `T` from the parameters, it will end up just inferring `Shape`, since `T['kind']` isn't a great inference site for `T`.

Anyway, hope that helps.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing we need to deal with is binding shapes with their respective kinds. Your original solution:

```
/**
 * Bad — doesn't bind the `Shape` with its `kind`. It allows calling `fetch<Square>('circle', 'foo')`.
 */
declare function fetch<T extends Shape>(type: Shape['kind'], id: string): T;
```

Instead, tell TypeScript that `type` needs to be not just any kind, but exactly the kind of the shape we are currently considering.

```
/**
 * Better: the `kind` is bound with its corresponding `Shape`. The downside: The exact return type is not inferred.
 */
declare function fetch<T extends Shape>(type: T['kind'], id: string): T;

const oups = fetch<Square>('circle', 'foo'); // $ExpectError
const shape = fetch('circle', 'foo');        // $ExpectType Shape
```

This is better, but the return type is just a `Shape`. We can do better by specifying overloads for your function:

```
/**
 * Using overloads can help you determine the exact return type.
 */
declare function fetch(type: 'circle', id: string): Circle;
declare function fetch(type: 'square', id: string): Square;
declare function fetch(type: 'rectangle', id: string): Rectangle;

const circle = fetch('circle', 'foo'); // $ExpectType Circle
```

This will give you exact return types, but for the cost of having to write more code. One might also argue there is some redundancy — the connection between a shape and its kind is encapsulated in its interface already, so repeating it in a form of overload seems less than perfect.